# HttpContextAccessor, IPrincipal and ServiceCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

Is there a way that I could implement next behaviour?

```
public static void Configure(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddScoped(typeof(Func<IPrincipal>), ???);
    services.AddInstance(typeof(Func<IPrincipal>), ???);
}
```

*1. Does not work:*

```
Func<IServiceProvider, IPrincipal> getPrincipal = 
    (sp) => sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User;

services.AddScoped(
    typeof(Func<IPrincipal>), 
    getPrincipal);
```

*2. Does not work:*

```
var builder = services.BuildServiceProvider();

services.AddInstance(
    typeof(Func<IPrincipal>),
    builder.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It is not clear what end result you require. For instance, are you wanting to have a service that returns the current user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution:

```
Func<IServiceProvider, IPrincipal> getPrincipal = 
    (sp) => sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User;

services.AddScoped(typeof(Func<IPrincipal>), sp => {
    Func<IPrincipal> func = () => {
        return getPrincipal(sp);
    };

    return func;
});
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap it around a delegate. `AddScoped` has two overloads. One where you can pass in the concrete types and one where you pass a factory method. When using the factory overload, the factory will be called every time when the type needs to be instantiated. Or is there a particular reason why you need it as delegate?

Comment: At my current task i have to inject `Func<IPrincipal>` in constructor as an argument

Answer (score 10):

```
Func<IServiceProvider, IPrincipal> getPrincipal = 
    (sp) => sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User;

services.AddScoped(
    typeof(Func<IPrincipal>), 
    getPrincipal);
```

You are trying to resolve the delegate, but I assume you want to resolve `IPrincipal` instead. I assume your service may look like this

```
public class MyService : IMyService 
{
    public MyService(IPrincipal principal) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If so, then your registration is wrong. You are registering `Func<IPrincipal>` but expecting `IPrincipal`which isn't registered.

You should either register the factory for `IPrincipal` or (less recommended imho) inject the `Func<IPrincipal>` into your service.

```
Func<IServiceProvider, IPrincipal> getPrincipal = 
    (sp) => sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User;

services.AddScoped<IPrincipal>(getPrincipal);
```

or shorter

```
services.AddScoped<IPrincipal>(
    (sp) => sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User
);
```

or

```
public class MyService : IMyService 
{
    priate IPrincipal principal;
    public MyService(Func<IPrincipal> principalFactory) 
    {
        this.principal = principalFactory();
    }
}
```